# Safari Error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork -10

Tags: css, safari, base64, data-uri

I am attempting to load a data-uri in an external CSS file. Here is the code:

```
.icon-blank-page-large {
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
```

}

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari fails to load the image and logs the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -10.)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps oddly, error code -10 seems to be undocumented for CFNetwork

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error was being caused by an incorrect encoding. A part of the base64 string was missing, though it still worked in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I re-encoded the image in base64. Turned out I was missing a == character at the end