# cargo doc --run does not load the doc in Safari properly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried cargo doc --run and it doesn't load the docs properly.[image: Safari screenshot]

Comment: Please open the developer tools in Safari and share any errors you see in the console there.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error @PitaJ in Safari.  Works fine in Chrome.  Since it isn't my question, doesn't seem I can upload a screenshot.  The specific error which occurs multiple times is "Failed to load resource: The operation couldn't be complete. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.).  I'm using Safari 15.6 under macOS Monterey 12.5 on a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip.

Comment: Here is more information on the error:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678971/safari-error-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-10

Seems to be a problem with rustdoc?

Comment: There is a problem documented with the Rust project that seems to be related.  It implies that opening the developer menu fixes it.  However, this fix did not work for me:  https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85444